# Por qué se usa el operador % para obtener ciertas cifras

Tags: java

Viendo por internet formas de resolver distintos problemas, he visto que muchas veces se usa el operador % para obtener una o varias cifras. No termino de entender por qué lo usan y cómo es que se obtiene el resultado que se quiere, por ejemplo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        int dia, mes, anno, suma, numeroSuerte = 0;
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Introduzca el día de nacimiento: ");
        dia = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Introduzca el mes de nacimiento: ");
        mes = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Introduzca el año de nacimiento: ");
        anno = scanner.nextInt();
                
        suma = dia + mes + anno;
        while (suma != 0) {
            numeroSuerte = numeroSuerte + (suma % 10); //Es aquí donde me fijo que se encuentra el % y no entiendo como funciona.
            suma = suma / 10;
        }
        
        System.out.print("Su numero de la suerte es " + numeroSuerte);
                
    }

}
```

Gracias por la explicación :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**%** es un **operador aritmético** que devuelve el **resto de una división**, cuando divides dos números y su división no es entera esta división tiene un resto o residuo r ejemplo **8 % 2** da como resto **0** ya que su división es exacta, no da un número decimal, ahora bien, **8 % 3** da un residuo de **2** ya que su división no es exacta **8 / 3** da un número decimal, puedes comprobarlo tú mismo con cualquier calculadora , para entender mejor puedes buscar en internet el **algoritmo de Euclides** que explica cómo se haya este residuo, e incluso puedes programarlo en el lenguaje que desees, creo que sería un buen ejercicio.

Answer (score 0):

El % en operaciones matemáticas normalmente se utiliza para saber el *resto* de una división entera.

```
// 3 * 4 + 1 = 13... por lo tanto
13 / 3; // daria 4
13 % 3; // daria 1
```